# Ratio of decidable problems

Tags: computability, undecidability

Consider decision problems stated in some “reasonable” formal language. Let's say formulae in higher-order Peano arithmetic with one free variable as a frame of reference, but I'm equally interested in other models of computation: Diophantine equations, word problems from rewriting rules using Turing machines, etc. An answer expressed in any classical formalization would be fine, though if you know how much the choice of formalization influences the answer, that would also be interesting.

Given the length $N$ of the statement of a decision problem, we can define the number $D(N)$ of decidable statements of length $N$ and the number $U(N)$ of undecidable statements of length $N$.

What is known about the relative growth of $U(N)$ and $D(N)$? In other words, if I take a well-formed decision problem at random, what is the probability of its being decidable for a given statement length?

<sub>Inspired by [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-factors-make-a-problem-decidable) which asks whether “most problems and algorithms [are] decidable”. Well, if you don't filter by interest, are they?</sub>

Comment: So, you are essentially asking how big a fraction of *describable* languages are decidable? If we consider all languages, then this fraction is obviously 0 as there are uncountably many languages.

Comment: @AlextenBrink More precisely, I'm asking how big a fraction of language descriptions are decidable languages. It might make a difference the number of equivalent descriptions of a language is correllated with its decidability. P.S. Feel free to edit my question if you don't think it's expressed clearly.

Comment: This seems somehow related to (and more complicated that) the Chaitin's constant but I am yet to find a way to say $D(N)$ is not computable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant

Comment: a related question: what is the probability that a random n-state Turing machine is decidable?

Comment: There is a notion of "NP-Complete Phase Transitions" (see [here](http://bit-player.org/bph-publications/AmSci-2002-03-Hayes-NPP.pdf), [here](http://leibniz.cs.huji.ac.il/tr/532.pdf) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.2.4475)) that begins to address the portion of satisfiable instances for randomly generated instances of NP-Complete problems.  I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for but maybe it's getting close.

Comment: I am unsure how you would encode a "problem statement" so that $N$ is a meaningful quantitiy. In particular, any given instance of *any* problem (on its own) is trivially decidable, so you really have to encode whole problems (or languages) finitely.

Comment: If I remember correctly, someone (JDH? or Carl Mummert?) answered a similar question on MO or [math.se]. I will post a link if I find it.

Comment: Here is a similar question on [math.se]: [Density of halting Turing machines](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73187/468)

Comment: @AlextenBrink, I don't follow.  That S' is a subset of an uncountable set S does not mean that the ratio of cardinalities |S'|/|S| = 0.  If the ratio is defined then it can be non-zero.  Consider the positive reals P vs reals in the range (0, 1) F.  For every element f in F, 1/f is not in F but is in P and for every p in P that is not in F, 1/p is in F and is in P.  So we have a 1:2 correspondance which suggest that |F|/|P| is more appropriately 1/2 than 0.

Comment: @MikeSamuel, I meant that a *countable* subset $S'$ of an uncountable set $S$ always covers a negligible fraction of $S$, as the set of descriptions is countable and the set of languages uncountable. For uncountable subsets, the answer could be anything indeed.

Answer (score 2):

See Chaitin's research into [Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) that shows, as I understand it, that undecidable problems are [paraphrasing] quite numerous, rampant or dense among statements chosen at random. However you have to be careful how you define $U(N)$ and $D(N)$ because they may be actually uncomputable functions. There is also some connections to [busy beaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) research. Identifying decidable and undecidable statements seems quite analogous to proving that busy beavers halt or do not halt. (e.g. some of all statements are in the form, “busy beaver [x] halts”).

Comment: Both functions are, of course uncomputable in general. However it is not excluded to find explicit bounds on their asymptotic ratio, just as one may find bounds on the number of uncompressible strings of size n.